# Exclude array items based on dynamic criteria

Tags: regex, string, powershell

I have an array of strings like:

- File1
- File2
- File1_s1
- File2_s1
- Print$
- PSDrive
- PSParentPath

I have a need to select all strings that do not conform to a dynamic set of rules. I don't really need fancy regex, I just want to match a dynamic amount of very simple regex rules. Basically:

```
$Arr | Where {($_.Name -notlike '_s1') -and ($_.Name -notlike 'Print$')}
```

But I need a dynamic amount of -ands specified by an input to the function. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: `-like` and `-notlike` do not support regex.

Comment: Yes... I know, they just do wildcard matches. I want the specified behavior of multiple simple wildcard matches, but a dynamic number of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you can do this

```
$omits = "_s1","Print$"
$regex = '({0})' -f (($omits | ForEach-Object{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join "|")

$arr | Where-Object{$_ -notmatch $regex}
```

`$omits` would contain the list of strings you want to `-match`/`-notmatch`. Then we take each member and run a regex escape on it ($ is a special regex character. The end of line anchor) The take each scrubbed string and build a matching group. So in the above example `$regex` would be

```
(_s1|Print\$)
```

Add more entries to `$omit` as you see fit. Which would give the filtered results as

```
File1
File2
PSDrive
PSParentPath
```

If you can be trusted to escape your own regex your options open up more.

```
$omits = "_s1","Print\$","^PS"
$regex = '({0})' -f ($omits -join "|")
```

That way the PS has to be at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Great! As a followup, is there a way, using this method, to exclude the entries beginning with PS? Is just adding PS to $omits overly broad, or would that work?

Comment: Currently it would match anywhere in the string. If you want to match positionally it would be easy but you would have to escape your own strings.

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but could you provide an example of what you mean? I can ensure that $omits is escaped properly.

Answer (score 0):

As the @Matt suggests, without wildcards in your strings `-NotLike` is basically equivalent to `-ne` (and then you could just use `-NotIn`).  I'm assuming your examples are missing wildcards but your actual patterns are not.

```
$patternArray = 'File1','File2','File1_s1','File2_s1','Print$','PSDrive','PSParentPath';
foreach ($pattern in $patternArray) {
    $Arr = $Arr | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike $pattern};
}
```

Or you could do some basic matching with:

```
$patternArray = 'File1','File2','File1_s1','File2_s1','Print$','PSDrive','PSParentPath';
foreach ($pattern in $patternArray) {
    $Arr = $Arr | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*$pattern*"};
}
```

Comment: I think I understand what you're suggesting, but as it written it makes no sense to me.'File1','File2', etc are $arr. Are you suggesting that $patternArray be the array of patterns to match against... like *_s1, *_s2?

Comment: @BryanWinstead What don't you understand?  You take the array of objects, `$Arr`, and the array of patterns.  Then, for each pattern, you remove the items in the array that match the pattern.  You assign the result back to `$Arr` so that the next time the loop runs the array of objects has the previous patterns already removed.

Comment: @BryanWinstead "Are you suggesting that $patternArray be the array of patterns to match against... like *_s1, *_s2?" Precisely.

Comment: @BaconBits I hit enter too early, sorry. As written it confused me as it's very late and I'm very tired atm. I know SO frowns on "thanks", but "thanks" to both you and Matt for helping so quickly.